# Get whole Property Object from RETS Server using PHRETS

Tags: rets

I am getting MLNumbers from RETS Server but now I need to get all the fields of all the MLNumbers and store into my database. Could anybody help me to write query to get the whole property Object.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the Listing Numbers then you just need to write a search query to pull all the results back and process the results. I haven't ever seen a field name MLNumber but you will have to figure that out:

```
<?php
$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property","RES","(MLNumber=11111,22222,33333)");
while ($listing = $rets->FetchRow($search)) {
    echo "Address: {$listing['StreetNumber']} {$listing['StreetName']}, ";
    echo "{$listing['City']}, ";
    echo "{$listing['State']} {$listing['ZipCode']} listed for ";
    echo "\$".number_format($listing['ListPrice'])."\n";
}
$rets->FreeResult($search);
```

I think this should return the results you need. You will need to figure out the Resource/Class/Field name you need to use for your SearchQuery().

More PHRETS examples [here](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/SearchQuery).